# Check in a firestore collection if there is an array with both values without considering the order

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function in React Native (I use the official library "@react-native-firebase")

Library Documentation: https://rnfirebase.io

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const handleSendMessage = async() => {

 const chatsRef = firestore().collection('chats');
 const members = [currentUser.uid, contact.uid];

 try {

   const querySnapshot = await chatsRef
    .where('members', 'array-contains', members)
    .get();

   //More code..
  
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
 }
};
```

but I have the need that the order in the array is not considered, so I can't write it like this.

I thought of a solution like this:

```
const querySnapshot = await chatsRef
     .where('members', 'array-contains', currentUser.uid)
     .where('members', 'array-contains', contact.uid)
     .get();
```

But it is not possible to write it, because the queries in firebase only support a single array-contains filter.

I also need both values checked and not just one, so I don't think I can use "array-contains-any"

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not provide a way to do this sort of query.  The best option you have, without changing your data, is to perform two different array-contains queries (one for each UID), then write code to look for documents in common between the results of those two queries.

If you are able to change your data, you could create a new field that contains a single string with the two UIDs concatenated, then query for that string.  So if you have `currentUser.uid` and `contact.uid`, you would:

1. Sort to the two values so they always occur in the same order
2. Concatenate them somehow (maybe "{uid1}-{uid2}")
3. Write the concatenated string into a new document field
4. Query that field using the same sorted, concatenated string

But this will not handle all the combinations of UIDs you might encounter.  It will only work for the two you choose to add.